# Launching an app only in portrait orientation

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

I'm trying to develop an app on Swift that supports both portrait and landscape orientations but I don't want that the user gets the possibility to launch it in landscape mode.
So is there a way to prevent this opening in landscape while keeping the app's device orientation parameters on portrait, landscape left and landscape right, or is there a way to change the device orientation parameters from portrait only after the launch of the app with the UIInterfaceOrientationMask ?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restrict it in AppDelegate's method -

```
var supportedOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientationMask = .portrait

func application(_ application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsFor window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return supportedOrientation  
}
```

Override following in all view controllers -

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    if let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate {
        var orientation: UIInterfaceOrientationMask = .all
        delegate.supportedOrientation = orientation
    }
}
```

Try it and let me know if it works.

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work, the whole app stays in portrait mode. Nothing moves when I change the orientation of the device.
The general parameters are still portrait, landscape left and right.

Comment: Yes I think it's working great! I will fully look at it later but for now it seems to be great.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: How did you fix it from the not working on the 11th and working on the 12th @EdouardDemenois